# Exclude Directory from being forced to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have made this rewrite rule to force all my directories to https 
however i want one directory for not to be forced.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This is my rule its working fine .I tried excluding like this below but its not working .

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/WebsiteControl/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/WebsiteControl/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: still redirecting  http ://example.com/WebsiteControl to   https: //example.com/WebsiteControl

Comment: Yes, like @anubhava said, try with other browser, to bypass the cache problems